# ListView1_ItemChecked event in c# 2008

Tags: c#

How to call the ListView1_ItemChecked event in the buttonclick event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to simulate the checked event.

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     ListViewItem item = // get the item you want
     ItemCheckedEventArgs checkedArgs = new ItemCheckedEventArgs(item);
     ListView1.ItemChecked(sender, checkedArgs);
}
```